# Jest has empty name property in arrow function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

Right now I'm using:

**node.js**: 9.8.0

**Jest**: 23.4.2

**ts-jest**: 23.1.3

**typescript**: 2.9.2

And when trying to doing the following in my *.test.ts files:

```js
const foo = () => 'bar';

console.log(foo.name); // ''
```

**foo** has the property *name* in it but is empty. I've run the same code in a separate *.ts file, just to know whether or not was some *.tsconfig* setting, but the console prints out 'foo' as expected.

Could anyone help me out? Any ideas would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
const foo = () => 'bar';

console.log(foo.name);
```

Yes foo.name doesn't exist .

```
const foo = () => 'bar';
```

means

> const foo = function() { return 'bar'};

and when you do  console.log(foo.name);

there is no such `name` value  in foo , because foo is a function

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name